# How is the scope of a nested universal quantifier determined (higher-rank types)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, quantifiers, unification, higher-rank-types

Originally I assumed the scope of a nested universal quantifier on the LHS of a function type can be determined purely syntactical, i.e. everything inside the parenthesis of `(forall a. a -> b) -> Bool` is within the same scope. However, this assumption is wrong:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

fun :: (forall a. [a] -> b) -> Bool
fun _ = undefined

arg :: c -> c
arg _ = undefined

r = fun arg -- type variable a would escape its scope
```

This makes sense, because in `fun` `b` must be chosen before `a` and thus be fixed or independent of `a`. During unification the argument type `c -> c` would force `b`'s instantiation with `[a0]` though.

So maybe scoping at the type level rather resembles that of functions at the term level, where the result value is clearly not part of the function's scope. In other words if `b` weren't the codomain of the function type, the type checker would pass. Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with an annotation that supports my reasoning.

A more restrictive way would be to disallow the instantiation of rigid type variables with any flexible one of the same annotation during unification. Both ways seem legitimate to me, but how does this actually work in Haskell?

Comment: For any variables that don't have an explicit `forall`, an implicit one is inserted right after the nearest `::`, so your example is equivalent to `fun :: forall b. (forall a. [a] -> b) -> Bool`

Comment: I find it very helpful to think about `forall` as type-level equivalent of lambda. Term-level equivalent of your example would look something like ``fun = \b -> (\a -> [a] `foo` b) `bar` True``

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, that sounds a bit off to me. Type lambdas are term-level things in languages supporting them. Haskell's `forall` is just a way to make type arguments explicit in type signatures. `forall a. [a] -> b` is the type of a term whose first argument is a type, `a`, and whose second argument is a value of type `a`.

Comment: @dfeuer They're not "just a way to make explicit", they are important for specifying scope. Before rank-N types there was only one possible scope, so Haskell didn't have `forall`, but now that scopes can be different it's suddenly necessary. Check out [this article](https://medium.com/collegevine-product/forall-is-the-type-level-lambda-9237b4ca6827) I wrote some time ago, it has a bit more on the subject.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, right, they specify scope. They bind names, like lambdas do, but they're otherwise quite different.

Comment: Well, I didn't say they were the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-quantified type variables are implicitly quantified at the top-level. Your types are equivalent to

```
fun :: forall b . (forall a. [a] -> b) -> Bool
arg :: forall c . c -> c
```

Hence, the scope of `b` is the whole type.

You can think of each `forall`'ed variable as a kind of implicit additional type argument the function receives. I think you understand that, in a signature like

```
foo :: Int -> (String -> Bool) -> Char
```

the `Int` value is chosen by the caller of `foo`, while the `String` value is chosen by `foo` when (and if) it calls the function passed as a second argument.

In the same spirit,

```
fun :: forall b. (forall a. [a] -> b) -> Bool
```

means that `b` is chosen by the caller of `fun`, while `a` is chosen by `fun` itself.

The caller can indeed pass the `b` type explicitly using `TypeAnnotations` and write

```
fun @Int :: (forall a. [a] -> Int) -> Bool
```

After that, an argument of type `forall a. [a] -> Int` must be apssed, and `length` fits such polymorphic type.

```
fun @Int length :: Bool
```

Since this is the call site for `fun` we don't get to see where the "type argument" `a` is passed. That indeed can only be found in the definition of `fun`.

Well, it turns out that it's not really possible to define a `fun` which that type that makes a meaningful call to its argument (`length`, above). It would be if we had a slightly different signature like this:

```
fun :: forall b. Eq b => (forall a. [a] -> b) -> Bool
fun f = f @Int [1,2,3] /= f @Bool [True, False]
```

Here we can see that `f` (to be bound to `length` by the call) is called twice at two distinct types. This produces two values of type `b` that can then be compared to produce the final `Bool`.